# Form not submitting when using client side validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using *jquery.validate.js*,validation is working fine when I use `$("#formUserEdit").submit(function (e)`

But when I use `$('#btnModify').on('click', function (event) {`, form submitted successfully without checking validation. I don't know what is issue behind this. I am submitting form data by json.

```
<form id="formUserEdit" method="post" action="#" >
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                <label for="txtFIRSTNAME">First Name</label>

                                <input id="txtFIRSTNAME" type="text" name="txtFIRSTNAME" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" />
                                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="txtFIRSTNAME1"></span>
                                <input type="hidden" id="txtId" />
                            </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnModify">OK</button>
<form>

    $(document).ready(function () {
    rules: {
                txtFIRSTNAME: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 128,
                    required: true
                }, },
            highlight: function (element) {
                var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("#formUserEdit").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    }
```

Comment: try changing type="submit" to type ="button"

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not have close tag

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ,the below function, this blocks the default event of submit

```
$("#formUserEdit").submit(function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

}
```